# json serializer with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json

my question is want to display my date in %B %d format python 
actually i done with with my conversion of date and now the problem is when is pass that array (today_data) to json serializer it wont work.here is my code as follows:
im new to django can u help thanx in advance.

```
def today_event(request):
    today_event = scene()

    now = datetime.now()
    now = str(now.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
    current_date_time = datetime.strptime(now,"%d %B %Y")
    today_event = scene.objects.filter(startdate=current_date_time)

    today_data = []
    for today in today_event:
        today.startdate = today.startdate.strftime("%B %d")
        today_data.append(today)    

    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    data_event = json_serializer.serialize(today_data, ensure_ascii=False)
    return HttpResponse(data_event)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with dates. It is simply that the `serializers` module is just for querysets. You have a standard list, so just use the basic `simplejson` module:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
data_event = simplejson.dumps(today_data)
```

Comment: actually i want to display july 06  so thats why i use  today_event = scene.objects.filter(startdate=current_date_time)

    today_data = []
    for today in today_event:
        today.startdate = today.startdate.strftime("%B %d")
        today_data.append(today)    

    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    data_event = json_serializer.serialize(today_data, ensure_ascii=False)
    return HttpResponse(data_event)

Comment: Why did you 1) ignore my answer (which is correct) and 2) repost the same code (in an unreadable format)? What's the point of asking a question if you're not listening to the replies?